# Is there a way to specify the ExecutorService for RestClient with declarative/annotation approach?

Tags: helidon

Context is not being propagated when we invoke the other service endpoint with asynchronous Rest Client,
so we are instantiating the RestClient with Builder like the following code snippet and specifying the ExecutorService to use when invoking asynchronous Rest Client. The specified ThreadPoolSupplier internally calling the Contexts.wrap(ExecutorService toWrap), so the context is being propagated to its Threads.

```
    @Inject
    public IndexDeployer(ExecutorServiceSupplier threadPoolSupplier) {

        this.indexClient = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                .baseUri(URI.create("http://localhost:7071"))
                .register(DefaultMicroprofileRestClientExceptionMapper.class)
                .executorService(threadPoolSupplier.get())
                .build(IndexClient.class);
    }
```

Earlier Rest Client Config Sample:

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey="indexClient")
@RegisterProvider(value = DefaultMicroprofileRestClientExceptionMapper.class, priority = 50)
public interface IndexClient {
```

Would you please suggest if there is a way to specify the ExecutorService for RestClient with annotations ? (so that we can go with old code with annotations instead of instantiating the RestClient with Builder )

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Microprofile RestClient Specification Doc particularly on the use of Custom ExecutorService](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-3.0/microprofile-rest-client-spec-3.0.html#_executorservice) , the only way is the programmatic call to RestClientBuilder that you’ve mentioned. Unfortunately, it does not mention of any way to do it on the declarative/annotation approach. If you don’t specify/set the executorService, like when using the annotation, it looks like that RestClientBuilderImpl will create a new executorService for you:

```
RestClientBuilderImpl() {
    this.configWrapper = new ConfigWrapper(this.clientBuilder.getConfiguration());
    this.executorService = Executors::newCachedThreadPool;
}
```

Not sure if this will help or apply to your scenario, but looking further, if you use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.helidon.microprofile.rest-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>helidon-microprofile-rest-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

for your rest client, that the created executorService from RequestClientBuilder will undergo **Context.wrap()** as shown in this code: https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/blob/helidon-3.x/microprofile/rest-client/src/main/java/io/helidon/microprofile/restclient/MpRestClientListener.java#L44-L48.

Comment: Thank you!
We were using jersey-mp-rest-client
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.microprofile</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-mp-rest-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
after switched to helidon-microprofile-rest-client, MpRestClientListener is calling Context.wrap() and context is being propagated.